# Azure - Create Ubuntu VM with larger OS disk

Tags: azure, ubuntu, iaas

How can I create an Ubuntu VM with an OS disk larger than the default size of 30GB? I tried increasing the disk size after creating the VM (after deallocating). But the system was throwing an error that it cannot find the disk in the resource group.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this for ubuntu but could you create your disk first as a resource then create your vm with the option of attaching an existing disk?

Comment: I will try this. I know data disks can be attached, but not sure about os disks.

Answer (score 0):

To create an Ubuntu VM with the OS disk larger than the default 30GB, you can use the ways such as Azure CLI, template and etc. But you cannot do that in the Azure portal.

And you can also expand the existing VM OS disk size in the Azure portal in the VM Disk blade. Click the disk and select the OS disk. Then change the size in the configuration blade. Of curse, you need to make sure the VM is already in the stopped state first.

Additional, the [VM size](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/sizes) also affects the amount of free space on the disk. So a suitable VM size is also the necessary for you.

Comment: I tried using cli and from blade (after de allocation). It was throwing an error - disk cannot be found.

Comment: @KolithadeSilva Do you find the disk resource and what VM size do you use?

Comment: I was using a 16 core, 32gb vm. I could see the disk resource from the blade, but not from cloud shell.

Comment: @KolithadeSilva As I said you can change the disk size in the portal. In the cloud shell, you need to show the disk with the disk name and group or the resource id when the disk is a managed disk.

Comment: @KolithadeSilva Any more questions? Does it solve your problem?

Comment: @KolithadeSilva Can you provide the screenshots to show what you did in your question?

Comment: @CharlesXu  I cannot see how I can change the OS disk size for my Ubuntu VM. The VM is stopped already and I can only attach or edit the data disk, but not the OS disk

Comment: @user2335065 You need to post another question and provide more messages so that we can help you better.

Comment: I tried increasing the size after creation. First, stop the vm, and modify the disk size in the portal. Second, use parted to resize the partition to the new max size. Unfortunately, these steps seem incomplete, as the VM was broken, and I could not do much with it after that. "sudo apt-get update" threw memory errors.